# JS simulate manually keypress on input

Tags: javascript, html

i am trying to fill an Input-text in HTML page  via javascript (chrome extension).

> ```
> const inputNom = document.querySelector('....');
>
> inputNom.value = 'Jean ...';
> ```

works fine and i can see the input value in the Input-text.

By clicking the submit button,
its looks like  the `informations validator` in the submit button only detects the value if it is entered manually.

is there some way to simulate a manually keypress on this input.

thank you every body

Comment: Depends how the validator is validating - we'd need to see its code to see how to get it to pass the tests it's running

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to simulate key press events programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/is-it-possible-to-simulate-key-press-events-programmatically)

Comment: i try __inputNom.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keypress',{'key':'a'}));
__ and no luck